# How can I upgrade react-native gradle version

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, version, upgrade, react-native

I need help.
I can't upgrade gradle version of my react-native project.

I try a lot of things, downloaded last version of Android Studio & SDK Tools etc.

I changed this file \android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties, I tried to upgrade using `npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade` but still I can't upgrade it.

When I react-native eject It's exports 
"**distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip**"

Waiting for answers.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In android/build.gradle you have to edit this line

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.y.z'

Change **x.y.z** with the version you want. Edit it with Android Studio then click **Sync now**

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked!  react-native-google-maps

Comment: How to understand which gradle version I need to update to?

Comment: @Vadim I have found this link helpful to understand which gradle version you need to update https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle

Comment: But that's the Gradle Tools version for Android, not Gradle itself.

Comment: Everytime I do this, it corrupts my entire project. Gradle is the worst, I mean the worst. days, weeks wasted on their horrible compatibility.

Comment: @Ezos I completely agree. :(

Comment: i use to npx react-native@latest init  a_new_project just to check which react-native version they are using with which gradle version

Answer (score 12):

In {yourProject}\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties, update:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-{your version}.zip
```

Find your version of gradle with

```
gradle --version
```

You may need to install gradle wrapper if you haven't already.

Comment: From where come the {version} used on the distributionUrl parameter (https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-{version}.zip)? Normaly I create my project and I need update to a newer version changing this parameter manualy.

Answer (score 10):

you can go to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ and check that latest -all.zip version of gradle and update the same in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file. When you run your react-native app the next time, your gradle will first get upgraded and then run.

Answer (score 6):

There are two things

1. **Android Gradle Plugin**

   You can see the version of it in **android/build.gradle** file and update it using Daniel's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481885/13825846)
2. **Gradle version**

   You can see this in **android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties** file and update it using the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61667539/13825846)

To know the difference between them refer following links:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

[difference between android gradle plugin and gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49156528/difference-between-android-gradle-plugin-and-gradle)

Comment: You can simply edit both it in the menu in Android Studio at `File > Project Structure > Project`

Answer (score 3):

From Gradle's site:

https://gradle.org/install/#with-the-gradle-wrapper

> Upgrade with the Gradle Wrapper If your existing Gradle-based build
> uses the Gradle Wrapper, you can easily upgrade by running the wrapper
> task, specifying the desired Gradle version:
>
> `$ ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=6.6.1 --distribution-type=bin`
> Note that it is not necessary for Gradle to be installed to use the
> Gradle wrapper. The next invocation of gradlew or gradlew.bat will
> download and cache the specified version of Gradle.
>
> $ `./gradlew tasks`
> Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip ...

**Run these commands in your project's android folder**

Answer (score 2):

Open Android Studio and navigate to File → Project Structure

[image]

Then click on the Project option.

[image]

then choose the latest version of Gradle. After that click on Ok.

Answer (score 1):

I had opened my project in Terminal and ran `open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app` to open Android Studio but so that it can access node to download my gradle version which it did automatically.

Learned from this original post: [React Native on Android: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922174/react-native-on-android-cannot-run-program-node-error-2-no-such-file-or-dir)

Answer (score 0):

For react native
Go to File -> Project Structure -> Change gradle version to 6.1.1 plugin version to 4.0.0
Try different combinations
Use this link - https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle

Answer (score 0):

you can directly update gradle version which you want,

for example

1. update gradle version to 8.0.2
2. sync project

I hope it's work for you guys

Answer (score 0):

Check Gradle Releases: Visit the Gradle releases page (https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) to find a compatible version. Ideally, choose a stable release and avoid RC (release candidate) versions. Opt for versions ending in -all.zip.

Update *gradle-wrapper.properties*: Open the gradle-wrapper.properties file and edit the distributionUrl property. Replace the existing URL with the one you obtained from the Gradle releases page for your desired version (e.g., distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip).

Update Gradle: Run the following command in your project's root directory (replace 7.5.1 with the actual version you chose):

```js
 ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=7.5.1
```