# How can I upgrade react-native gradle version automatically

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle

I need help

**Question 1:**

when I create a new project in Android Studio, the project create according to the latest gradle 8.0. but when I create react native project, the project create gradle-7.5.1-all.
Is there a way that create react native project base on last version of gradle automatically?

Gradle-wrapper.properties after install react native project
[image]

Ghange gradle-wrapper.properties manually
[image]

build.gradle
[image]

**Qustion 2:**

after change version of gradle in gradle-wrapper.properties manually, How to **sync** react native project in Android Studio.
according to the bellow images, The project setting in android studio projects is different with project setting in react native project just open with android studio.

Project Structure Setting in Android Studio
[image]

Project Structure Setting when open react native project with Android Studio
[image]

My problem is after executing react native project, it shows below errors.

run react native project in order to upgrade gradle, but errors:

[image]

Thanks for your time

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479691/how-can-i-upgrade-react-native-gradle-version

Comment: I do all the solutions  in corresponding post, but I still cannot upgrade gradle.