# React Native: What's the difference between gradle references in gradle-wrapper.properties and build.gradle?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

In my React Native app, I got an error about incompatibilities with `gradle 6`, so I looked in my project structure to find out which version of gradle I was running in my project. I found this line in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip
```

and this line in `build.gradle`

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")
```

**What I Want To Know:** What's the difference between the reference to gradle in each of these files? In other words, how is version 5.5 being used in my project, and how is 3.4.2 being used?

Answer (score 6):

`distributionUrl` represents `Gradel` Version where as `classpath` represents `Android Gradle plugin` version.

`Gradel` vs `Android Gradle plugin`: Reffer this [difference between android gradle plugin and gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49156528/difference-between-android-gradle-plugin-and-gradle)

[Gradle](https://gradle.org/guides/#getting-started) is the build system.

You can use it with [a lot of plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html). One of these is the [plugin for Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html).
It is used to provide processes and configurable settings that are **specific** to building and testing **Android** applications.

For greater details and mapping of the above two type of versions refer the following URLs
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin

I hope this answer has cleared your doubts.